# Remove all non digit characters by T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I use Sql-Server 2008 and have a table with `phonenumer` column by type `NVARCHAR(20)`, in this table there is a lot of kind of data like the following

```
phone number
-------------
0913-876-9876
+941-9145678921
9176523461
915 986 23 45
...
```

I am interesting to transfer this values to new table with correct format, in first step I need an script to remove all non digit characters for example I need a select script to above data returns me the following values :

```
phone number
-------------
09138769876
9419145678921
9176523461
9159862345
...
```

Does any one have any idea about it?